# GraphQL with LARAVEL Lighthouse PHP - How to hide attributes?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

The title says it all.

If I have something like this:

```
type Model {
  id
  name
}
```

and only specific users should be able to access the `ID` field. How I can do it?

Same thing if specific users can access only `Model > relationship` data. How I can hide attributes based on the user capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@can`](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#can) directive, like:

```
type Model {
    id: ID! @can(...)
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detailed answer, please? For example, if you have @hasMany directive for relationship data, how you return only records that the given user can see?

Comment: Also, error `Type 'Int' on 'attribute_name' can not be found in the schema.` if I use ´@can` after types attributes as you have shown in your answer

Comment: @CecilyMiller If you need to remove records from you relationship like a HasMany directive, you can use a scope to reduce what models are returned.

Comment: @CecilyMiller You second question is hard to say more about without seeing some actual code.